# Please undelete Question on interest rates of Bank Loans?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I apologise should I err, but did I ever ask a question about the seemingly low interest rates of bank loans? If it were deleted, would you please undelete it so that it can be read and help others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did.

[Why do banks offer/tender these loans at these low rates?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/28304/why-do-banks-offer-tender-these-loans-at-these-low-rates)

It was closed with good reason. It appeared to be an economic question, not really PF. More important, the premise was flawed, you asked why rates in HK were lower than in US, but the annual APR was higher than I'd see in the US for secured loans. 
I don't see how any edit would improve the question.